# SEGFAULT after recv from socket

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, pthreads

I have next trouble: after receiving data from sockets, server app generates segfault and shutdown. Code of client and server side are below.

server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <vector>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

static const int PORT= 20202;
static const string HOST = "127.0.0.1";
static const int MAX_CLIENTS = 10;


struct THREADINFO {
pthread_t thread_ID;
int sockfd;
string nick;
};

struct PACKAGE{
    string nick;
    string buff;
};


int compare( THREADINFO *a,  THREADINFO *b) {
    return a->sockfd - b->sockfd;
}



int sockfd, newfd;
THREADINFO thread_info[10];
vector<THREADINFO> client_list;
pthread_mutex_t clientlist_mutex;
void *client_handler(void *fd);
int main(){
    int err_ret, sin_size;
    sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;
    pthread_mutex_init(&clientlist_mutex, NULL);

    /* open a socket */
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        err_ret = errno;
        cerr << "socket() failed..." <<endl;
        return err_ret;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST.c_str());
    memset(&(serv_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);

    if(bind(sockfd, (sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(sockaddr)) == -1) {
        err_ret = errno;
        cerr << "bind() failed..." <<endl;
        return err_ret;
    }

    if(listen(sockfd, MAX_CLIENTS) == -1) {
        err_ret = errno;
        cerr << "listen() failed...." <<endl;

        return err_ret;
    }

    cout << "Starting socket listener.." << endl;
    while(1) {
        sin_size = sizeof( sockaddr_in);
        if((newfd = accept(sockfd, ( sockaddr *)&client_addr, (socklen_t*)&sin_size)) == -1) {
            err_ret = errno;
            cerr << "accept() failed..." <<endl;
            return err_ret;
        }
        else {
            if(client_list.size() == MAX_CLIENTS) {
                cerr << "Connection full, request rejected..." <<endl;
                continue;
            }
            cout << "Connection requested received"<<endl;
            THREADINFO threadinfo;
            threadinfo.sockfd = newfd;
            threadinfo.nick = "Anonymous";
            pthread_mutex_lock(&clientlist_mutex);
            client_list.push_back(threadinfo);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&clientlist_mutex);
            pthread_create(&threadinfo.thread_ID, NULL, client_handler, (void *)&threadinfo);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

vector<THREADINFO>::iterator findThread(vector<THREADINFO>& vector1,THREADINFO& threadInfo){

    for (auto item = vector1.begin();item != vector1.end();++item){
        if (compare(&(*item),&threadInfo) == 0){
            return item;
        }
    }
}

void *client_handler(void *fd) {
     THREADINFO threadinfo = *(THREADINFO *)fd;
     PACKAGE package;
        int bytes, sent;
        while(1) {
        bytes = recv(threadinfo.sockfd, (void *)&package, sizeof(PACKAGE), 0);
        if(!bytes) {
            cerr << "Connection lost from " << threadinfo.nick;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&clientlist_mutex);
            if (!client_list.empty()) {
                client_list.erase(findThread(client_list,threadinfo));
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&clientlist_mutex);
            break;
        }
            cout<< package.nick << " : " << package.buff << endl;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&clientlist_mutex);
                for (size_t i=0;i<client_list.size();i++){
                 PACKAGE spacket;
                if(!compare(&client_list[i], &threadinfo)) continue;
                    spacket.nick = package.nick;
                    spacket.buff = package.buff;
                    sent = send(client_list[i].sockfd, (void *)&spacket, sizeof( PACKAGE), 0);

                }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&clientlist_mutex);


         if(package.buff.compare("exit") == 0) {
             cout << "Client is disconnected" << endl;

            pthread_mutex_lock(&clientlist_mutex);
             if (!client_list.empty()) {
                 client_list.erase(findThread(client_list,threadinfo));
             }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&clientlist_mutex);
            break;
        }
        else {
             cerr << "Garbage data from " << threadinfo.sockfd <<" " <<threadinfo.nick;
        }
    }

    /* clean up */
    close(threadinfo.sockfd);

    return NULL;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

static const int PORT = 20202;
static const string HOST = "127.0.0.1";
void *receiver(void *param);

struct PackageInfo{
    string nick;
    string buff;
};

struct User{
    int sockfd;
    string nick;
};
struct ThreadInfo{
    pthread_t thread;
    int sockfd;

};


int isDisconnected,sockfd;


int connectWithServer(){
    int newfd, err_ret;
     sockaddr_in serv_addr;
     hostent *to;

    if((to = gethostbyname(HOST.c_str()))==NULL) {
        err_ret = errno;
        cerr<<"HOST ERROR" << endl;
        return err_ret;
    }

    if((newfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        err_ret = errno;
        cerr<<"SOCKET ERROR" << endl;
        return err_ret;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr = *(( in_addr *)to->h_addr);
    memset(&(serv_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);

    if(connect(newfd, ( sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof( sockaddr)) == -1) {
        err_ret = errno;
        cerr << "CONNECT ERROR"<<endl;
        return err_ret;
    }
    else {
        cout << "CONNECTED!"<<endl;
        return newfd;
    }
}

void login(User* client){
    if(isDisconnected){
        cerr << "You'are disconnected";
        return;
    }
    sockfd = connectWithServer();
    if(sockfd >= 0) {
        isDisconnected = 1;
        client->sockfd = sockfd;
        cout << "Logged in as " << client->nick << endl;
        ThreadInfo threadinfo;
        pthread_create(&threadinfo.thread, NULL, receiver, (void *)&threadinfo);

    }
    else {
        cerr << "Connection rejected..." << endl;
    }


}

void *receiver(void *param){
    int recvd;
    PackageInfo package;

    cout << "Waiting server..." << endl;

    while (isDisconnected){
        recvd = recv(sockfd, (void *)&package, sizeof( PackageInfo), 0);
        if (!recvd){
            cerr << "Connection lost";
            isDisconnected = 0;
            close(sockfd);
            break;
        }
        if(recvd > 0){
            cout << package.nick << " : " << package.buff<<endl;
        }
    }
    return NULL;

}

void sentToServer( User* client,string& message){
    int sent;
    PackageInfo package;

    if(!isDisconnected) {
        cerr << "\"You are not connected..." << endl;
        return;
    }

    package.nick = client->nick;
    package.buff = message;


    sent = send(sockfd, (void *)&package, sizeof(PackageInfo), 0);

}

int main() {
    User user;
    cout << "Enter nickname: ";
    getline(cin,user.nick);
    login(&user);
        string message;
    while (cin >> message){
        sentToServer(&user,message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In other words, client connected successfully. But after sending message, server generate segm fault error. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the code it seg faults at:

```
 cout<< package.nick << " : " << package.buff << endl;
```

Package is a struct with two members nick and buff. Then you read the socket with the size of PACKAGE struct which is size 16. I guess this is not really what you want. Maybe you could specify nick and buff as fixed length char arrays.

```
struct PACKAGE{ char nick[1024]; char buff[1024];};
```

Comment: Really. Thank's you. But i can't understand, why it's don't work wih std::string ?

Comment: You are reading the number of bytes that is the size of PACKAGE. The size of package is defined at compile time so you are just reading 16  bytes instead of the  complete message  from the  client.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `threadinfo.thread_ID` with any data. You should define new `pthread_t` and then pass it as an argument to `pthread_create()`